# Syntax Error while implementing Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to implement devise in my rails app, and getting a Syntax Error in my _header.html.erb partial:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <%= link_to "OpenDeals", root_path, id: "logo" %>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                <li><%= link_to "Home",    root_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
                <li>
                    <%= if user_signed_in? %>
                        Logged in as <strong><%= current.user.email %></strong>.
                        <%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path %>
                        <%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
                    <%= else %>
                        <%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path %> | 
                        <%= link_to 'Login', new_user_ssession_path %>
                    <%= end %>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

The error messages I am getting are:

/Users/adnankhan/code/opendeals/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:10: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
....append= ( if user_signed_in? );@output_buffer.safe_concat('
...                               ^
/Users/adnankhan/code/opendeals/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:14: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else
...);@output_buffer.append= ( else );@output_buffer.safe_concat...
...                               ^
/Users/adnankhan/code/opendeals/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:17: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
...');@output_buffer.append= ( end );@output_buffer.safe_concat...
...                               ^
/Users/adnankhan/code/opendeals/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:23: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
/Users/adnankhan/code/opendeals/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:25: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'

Greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if`, `else` and `end` should not start with  `<%=`, but with `<%`, because the returns are not supposed to be rendered

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Other mistakes that I corrected were misspelled 'session', and the fact that I had used 'restauranteur' instead of user in my model.